# How to solve "from _sqlite3 import * ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found." error

Tags: python, django, sqlite, path, dllimport

I'm beginner in Django . I use pycharm but when I want to run server with "python manage.py runserver"
in pycharm terminal It says "from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
".

Comment: have you tried to install _sqlite3 ??